# OSL: get a transform matrix from object face

Tags: osl

I'm trying to transform a vector to mesh's face transform space. Fairly easy to do for object's transform with a transform function using the "object" space, but I want to do this for a face instead. I'm guessing I need to find the face's transform  and use the transform function to transform the vector.

Comment: Z is easy enough.. how do you want to define X and Y?

Comment: So far I'm only dealing with rectangular polygons or right angle triangle faces. I guess X and Y would be the X and Y components of the longest edge of the triangle or the two edges that are perpendicular to each other.